# Profile folder, NetGetUserInfo and SHGetKnownFolderPath return different things for Active Directory and non-AD users

Tags: c++, c, windows, active-directory

Provided `LogonUser` can be used to retrieve an impersonation token also for an `Active Directory` user, I found myself at odds when trying to retrieve that user's profile directory.

`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, ...)` works for non AD users just fine, but it errors out for an AD user, even if their Profile path in the user's properties' Profile tab is set. The HRESULT it returns is `0x80070002`. I tried passing the flags `KF_FLAG_CREATE` and `KF_FLAG_DONT_VERIFY` to `SHGetKnownFolderPath`, but it doesn't help, same error.

On the other hand, `NetGetUserInfo(...)` returns an AD user's profile path correctly set in the `USER_INFO_4::usri4_profile` field, but returns an empty string for non-AD users.

Why is it so? How to get a consistent behavior? Is there any other API I could/should use?

---

**ANSWER:** Anders [has provided an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75166689/566849) to the dilemma, below. Read my comment there for more info.

Comment: `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` does not use `GetLastError()` to report errors, only the returned `HRESULT`. A value of `0x80070002` is `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)`. Any value you get from `GetLastError()` will be indeterminate, belonging to whatever APIs `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` happens to call internally (in this case, error code `298` is `ERROR_TOO_MANY_POSTS` - "Too many posts were made to a semaphore" - whatever that means).

Comment: That's fine, I just mentioned it for completeness sake. Regardless, I'd like to understand why it errors out, and how to avoid that. Removed mention of SetLastError from the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a token to `SHGetKnownFolderPath`, all it does is extracting the SID from the token and use that to look up the path under that users registry in HKU.

MSDN hints at this:

> In addition to passing the user's hToken, the registry hive of that specific user must be mounted.

You could try helping it by calling `LoadUserProfile` but I'm not sure what happens if that user has never logged into that specific machine before.

I'd say, try `SHGetKnownFolderPath` first since it can return paths customized on that specific computer. If it fails, try `NetGetUserInfo`.

Retrieving a users profile directory is not a common operation because regular programs are not supposed to store files there...

Comment: Indeed, `LoadUserProfile` was all it took to make it work, thanks! And [`LoadUserProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-loaduserprofilea) doc made me discover that the profile path returned by `GetNetUserInfo` is actually the *roaming profile* of the user, hence why it returned an empty string for the non-AD user.